# Can CHTMLView be used to display local file?

Tags: html, mfc

I would like to display a local file in html format. I can simply do:

```
void CMyhtmlView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
   CHtmlView::OnInitialUpdate();

   CMyhtmlDoc * pDoc =  (CMyhtmlDoc *) GetDocument();

   Navigate2 (pDoc->GetPathName() ,NULL,NULL);
}
```

and this displays an ascii file in the view but my real file is not ascii and it has to be decrepted first, plus obviously I want more control and display data in tables rather than plain text. Can I do that?

Assume a simple case where we multiply 10 numbers by 2 and display the results.

```
int num[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int multiplyBy = 2;
int result[10] = {0};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   result[i] = num[i] * multiplyBy;
}

// now display the results in html view
column1(number)     Column2(multiplayBy)   results(result)
1                   2                      2
2                   2                      4
3                   2                      6  
//and so on
```

Can this be done? Even if your example doesn't use tables, can we display dynamic data like this in htmlview and if so how? I am thinking the data is loaded by document and we can manipulate it already but it is a matter of displaying it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look at the HTMLEDIT sample?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. What you need to do:

1. Go to this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/dhtmldialog.aspx
2. Generate your html table
3. Use `IHTMLElement->put_outerHTML(_bstr_t("<table>.. my table data ..</table>"))` to put your html in some element with specified id

All you need its get IHTMLElement than you can do everything with your page.